# Selecting a field in a subquery to be part of outer query.Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery

How can I select a field that is in a where not exists subquery into the main query.
These 2 tables are not related in terms of foreign keys etc and I have not control over.

Let's take a fictious sample I have 2 tables  "Category-Order"

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Category](
        [Id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
        [Name] [varchar](255) NULL,
        [OrderName] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [CategoryType] [varchar](50) NULL

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Order](
        [OrderId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
        [OrderName] [varchar](50) NULL
    )
```

Given a query like below ,How can I rewrite the below query so that I can have CategoryType Selected as well?
At the moment I get the following error:

**"The multi-part identifier "C.CategoryType" could not be bound."**

```
        INSERT INTO Category(Name,OrderName,CategoryType)
        SELECT DISTINCT 'Fruit',O.OrderName , C.CategoryType
        FROM [Order]O
        WHERE NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT 1
            FROM Category c
            WHERE c.Name='Fruit'
                            AND C.OrderName=O.OrderName)
```

Or could you tell me the equivalent of the above query using a join and eliminating the where not exists

Many thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Felt like you want to populate Category table with relevant data from Order table. But Category type is not available in Order.
Can you give some more explanations over your requirement..

Comment: Basically the category table is used as a lookup if you like and if a name is not in the category table I need to add it. What is the equivalent joint query of a not exists ,may be that could be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use in the main query a table of the subquery.

You can do that :

```
INSERT INTO Category(Name,OrderName,CategoryType)
SELECT DISTINCT 'Fruit', O.OrderName , c.CategoryType
FROM [Order]O
    LEFT JOIN Category c
        ON c.OrderName=O.OrderName
    LEFT JOIN Category c2
        ON c2.OrderName=O.OrderName
        AND c2.Name = 'Fruit'
WHERE
    c.OrderName IS NOT NULL 
    AND c2.OrderName IS NULL
```

Or with ur exemple :

```
INSERT INTO Category(Name,OrderName,CategoryType)
SELECT DISTINCT 'Fruit',O.OrderName , Cat.CategoryType
FROM [Order]O
LEFT JOIN Category cat
    ON cat.OrderName=O.OrderName
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM Category c
    WHERE c.Name='Fruit'
    AND C.OrderName=O.OrderName)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.can you explain to me why the 2 joins? and how the query works in english.Need to understand in order to implement and suggest change

Comment: also I was looking at http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/t-sql-starters-simple-and-correlated-subqueries and it has an example of the equivalent of "not Exists" which is a bit different from your take.mmm .I wish my sql was better

Comment: 1st join is to get the name and the type of category, the 2nd join is only to exclude rows if there is a fruit category, the 2nd join is the not exists equivalent. you need 2 joins because you cannot retrieve informations from 2nd join when it's null and you want this join to be null. Check the select result tell me how it is. I think you can use `INNER JOIN` for the 1st join and remove the `c.OrderName IS NOT NULL AND` part.